# Formal word/phrase to refer to "year begin" effect

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to find a single word or perhaps an academic-sounding phrase to refer to the effect on something that results from the calendar year changing. I initially tried: "year begin effect" but this kind of sounds too caveman-ish.

One example sentence to frame the usage:

> The ______ effect was very noticeable this year, with sales growth
> across multiple product categories.

Comment: What's wrong with _New Year effect_?

Comment: Related, maybe: The formal (but not-very-formal-sounding) term [*fresh-start effect*](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/ritual-and-the-brain/201811/the-unexpected-science-fresh-starts-and-failures).

Comment: @TinfoilHat Hmm, ninja'ed by a minute :p Yeah, it's not exactly the same thing, but I think it's reasonably close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent study used the term [Fresh Start Effect](https://faculty.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Dai_Fresh_Start_2014_Mgmt_Sci.pdf) to describe changes in motivation caused by a temporal landmark, such as a new year, or even a new month, or a new week.

It's not too much of a stretch to use it in the context you want, which is to describe the general effect on something arising from a new calendar year

> The *Fresh Start Effect* was very noticeable this year, with sales growth across multiple product categories.